# Calculate the sum/difference of inputs stored as an array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a form with around 50 similar elements stored in a table.

For each item I have three records.

I have fetched the elements in a table as such:

```
    $table="SELECT * from hoa_list";
    $result=mysqli_query($db_conx,$table);
    $i=1;
    while($test = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="released[<?= $i ?>]" value="<?= $test['released']; ?>" onblur="recalculateSum();"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="spent[<?= $i ?>]" value="<?= $test['spent']; ?>" onblur="recalculateSum();"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="remain[<?= $i ?>]" value="<?= $test['remain']; ?>" readonly></td>
   </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
           } ?>
```

For each row i want to calculate the difference of first and second element and display it dynamically in the 3rd readonly input.
For elements without array i used the below code

```
<script>
function recalculateSum()
{
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("released").value);
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("spent").value);
    total = document.getElementById("remain").value = num1 + num2;
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to calculate the difference for elements stored in the table as doing it for each element is not possible because there are more than 50 rows. any code where i can iterate through each first and second element calculate its difference then move to the next row

Comment: I don't see any element with `id=released` here.

Comment: The javascript code is for different table where there was only one row. NOw i have multiple rows so how do i modify the above javascript code for array of inputs

Comment: If you want to stick to “old-school” event handling by assigning the handler function via HTML attributes, then pass a reference to the input element, `onblur="recalculateSum(this);"`, so that you can navigate your way up to the parent TR from there. Then you could use `getElementsByTagName` to get all inputs in that TR, and access them via index …

Comment: @misorude whats are the other new methods i can use instead of this event handler

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener would be the more current way of adding event handlers. (But you don’t necessarily have to use that now, the other version still works.)

Comment: @misorude can you help me with a snippet I get your idea but couldnt write the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function recalculateSum(elem) {
  var parent = elem.parentNode.parentNode, // navigate up to the TR
    inputfields = parent.getElementsByTagName("input"); // get all inputs in that TR

  // parse values of field 0 and 1 into integers, assign sum to field 2
  inputfields[2].value = parseInt(inputfields[0].value) + parseInt(inputfields[1].value)

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="released0" value="5" onblur="recalculateSum(this);"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="spent0" value="7" onblur="recalculateSum(this);"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="remain0" value="" readonly></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="released0" value="3" onblur="recalculateSum(this);"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="spent0" value="47" onblur="recalculateSum(this);"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" name="remain0" value=">" readonly></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps switch from `onblur` to `onchange`, then this will update automatically when the user uses the arrow buttons to change the field values, without the need to leave the field first.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But i get this warning after each input: The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: Yes onchange works better. And the warning is before i insert the second number. so i guess nothing to worry about. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, you might get a NaN, if one of the fields has no value set to begin with. If you make sure all fields have a value (0 at least, not an empty string), that issue should not arise. Otherwise the JS function could also be modified to check for an empty value first, and in that case return, or use 0 as a default value or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply transform your function into a loop.

```
function recalculateSum(count) {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById(`released${i}`).value)
    var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById(`spent${i}`).value)
    total = document.getElementById(`remain${i}`).value = num1 + num2
  }
}
```

Pass it in the size of the array and it will calculate based on the number of elements.

Comment: The size of array is 53. When i pass that count i get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at recalculateSum

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
function recalculateSum(){

var totalVal = 0;

$("#YouTableName tr").each(function(){

          totalValue += parseInt($(this).find('.Number1YouWantToAdd').val())+
          parseInt($(this).find('.Number2YouWantToAdd').val());

    });

return totalValue;
}
```

Comment: my table is huge with many rowspans and colspans and other columns. i have only posted the three columns